# How to pass a Pinia store from the app to a vue 3 library

Tags: webpack, vuejs3, vue-composition-api, pinia

I have a Vue 3 library that all my apps are using. Some of my apps uses Pinia and the library provides pinia stores as well.

My problem is that I do not know how to pass my pinia store to the library.

The apps and library use Vue 3 composition api with typescript and webpack.

Example:

App 1 has three stores.
Library has three stores.

How do I combine them so that all 6 stores are available and only injected once?

My Current solution (does not work)

App: (main.ts)

```js
const app = createApp(App);

const pinia = createPinia();
app.use(pinia);

// Lib gets injected here
app.use(VueNyx, { pinia });

router.isReady().then(() => {
  app.mount('#app');
});
```

Library: (index.ts (setup file for lib))

```js
export default {
  install: (
    app: App,
    options: { pinia?: Pinia } | null = null) => {
    // Global plugins
    if (!options?.pinia) {
      // If Vue app does not use pinia, create one
      app.use(createPinia());
    }

   ...

   // This store is defined in the lib which I want the app to be able to use as well.
   // Gives error here: 
   // Uncaught Error: []: "getActivePinia()" was called but there was no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
    useStripeStore().setStripeLoadedByDefault();
  },
};
```

If I call createPinia() in both the app and the library then the stores are added twice.

Comment: Hi, did u find the solution to the problem?